# Iterator for red-black binary search tree in C

Tags: c, iterator, red-black-tree

I need to find a point from red-black BST that is closest to a given point. To do so I have considered inorder traversal for which I need to keep track of minimum distance and nearest point at every instant.

I had to create one more struct which has a track of minimum distance and nearest point.

```
typedef struct minimum {
    point x;
    int m;
}minpoint;
```

**inorder traversal**

```
minpoint nearest(struct node *root,point p,minpoint min ){
    if (root == NULL)
        return min;
    min = nearest(root->left,p,min);
    if(distanceSquared(root->data,p) < min.m) {
    min.m=distanceSquared(root->data,p);
    min.x=root->data;
    }
    min =nearest(root->right,p,min);
    return min;
}
```

Is there a better or an optimum way to iterate through a red-black binary search tree?

structures of point and node are as follows:

**point**

```
typedef struct point2d {
    double x;
    double y;
}point;
```

**Node**

```
struct node{
    point data;
    char color;
    struct node *left, *right, *parent;
};
```

Comment: A tree is usually organized according to some principle. Do you know what the principle of organization is for your tree? Can we, for example, assume that nodes to the left have a lesser color, or a lesser x value, or a lesser distance from the origin, or what?

Comment: Red black tree is a self-balancing tree. It follows these conditions:
1) Every node has a color either red or black.
2) Root of tree is always black.
3) There are no two adjacent red nodes (A red node cannot have a red parent or red child).
4) Every path from a node (including root) to any of its descendant NULL node has the same number of black nodes.  [more info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/red-black-tree-set-1-introduction-2/).

Comment: The argument `minpoint min` is passing a copy of the `minpoint` struct. Modifying the copy has no effect on the caller's copy of the struct.

Comment: The code to traverse the tree looks fine. It visits each node exactly once, and that's the best you can do. (I'm assuming that you actually have a reason for using a tree.)

Comment: A red-black tree is normally a binary search tree. A binary search tree does not need inorder (or any other) traversal to find a value closest to something. You need to run a normal vanilla tree search. If you didn't find the exact value, you remember your node and go to the next larger (or previous smaller) node. One of the two will be the closest to your value. This is an O(log n) operation. Inorder traversal id O(n).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. that is only true if the tree nodes use the key that you are searching for. But if the tree is a search tree on, say, the `node.color` or on just the `node.data.x`, then there is no way to use it for distance relations.

Comment: @aghast You can have all kinds of crazy arrangements, like have a search tree and then search for something unrelated in it. But then you should state that in your question upfront. "I have a dictionary BUT I AM NOT USING THE KEY".

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. A red-black tree is only useful for searching in one dimension. For two-dimensional searching, you need a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or a [quad tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Comment: @user3386109 true bit it looks like OP wants to do a linear search. This makes little sense to me.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Agreed, it's not at all clear why the OP created the tree in the first place.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. This is a part of an assignment for which in level-1 I need to use O(N) and in level-2 I need to do the same in O(logN).

Comment: You are not using the BST property of your tree (you cannot use it in a 2D case). It isn't clear what purpose the tree serves. If the assignment is just to create an O(N) algorithm, put the points in an array or linked list or whatever. A BST won't be of any use in the O(log N) algorithm so you will need to replace it with some other structure anyway. If the assignment explicitly requires placing 2d points in a red-black tree, then I don't think it makes any sense.